# Retrieving the instance of a variable on which a data frame was split in R

Tags: r

To iterate over different splits of a data frame, I am trying to retrieve the category  on which it was split. Consider this basic set:

```
value <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
year <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012)
category <- c(X, X, X, Y, Y, Y)

Data <- data.frame(Value = value, Year = year, Category = category)
```

To find separate trends throughout years in terms of Value for each category, I split the set as follows:

```
Split_data <- split(Data, f = Category)
```

Then, I want to iterate over the set using a for-loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(Split_data){ 
   print(Split_data[i])
}
```

However, now I want to create a new data frame, in which I want to add the category from the specific split of the data frame.

```
for (i in 1:length(Split_data)){
  model <- lm(Value ~ year, data = Split_data[i])
  prediction <- data.frame(year = prediction_years, Value = rep(0, length(jaar)))
  prediction$Value <- predict(model, prediction)
  prediction$Category <- ????
  data <- rbind(data, prediction)
}
```

I know I can access it through Split_data$X$Category[1], but how do I do this during iteration?

I can access Splits of the set through Split_data[x], but Split_data[i]$Category returns NULL, Split_data[i][1] still returns a frame and I have no idea to do it differently.

I have tried retrieving the value from the list of columns in the original set, but the order in which the splits are organized in the split data frame seems to be random...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#object type
class(Split_data)
[1] "list"

#first list
Split_data[[1]]
#  Value Year Category
#1     1 2010        X
#2     2 2011        X
#3     3 2012        X

#first list and first column
Split_data[[1]][,1]
#[1] 1 2 3

#first list and first line
Split_data[[1]][1,]
#  Value Year Category
#1     1 2010        X

#first list, first line and first column
Split_data[[1]][1,1]
#[1] 1
```